# How do i correct an incorrect email address?

Tags: email

My wife's email address is *[name]*@icloud.com  However when I am sending  an email to her I start typing her email address I get this: *[name]*@icloud.com(DirectTV). I do not want Direct TV appended to her email address. What can I do?

Comment: You probably don't want that address posted in public, spam magnet. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

First check if the incorrect address is in Contacts. If so, you can just edit and correct it there.

If not, then it is probably stored in the address history. You can open this from the **Window->Previous Recipients** menu. You can search for the address in the dialog and delete it. (You might need to do this, even if you edit the email address in Contacts, as the wrong address might have been stored in the history.)